# Solving and graphing system of equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have a system of 3 equations with 4 variables, and I'm trying to graph the relationship between 3 variables with respect to the last variable. However, I am unsure of how to go about accomplishing this. Here's the base line code I have so far:

```
soln = NSolve[{
R = 8.3145101 ,
x = a / (a + b + c) ,
y = b / (a + b + c) ,
z = c / (a + b + c) ,
x * e ^ ( -23.78 * 10^3 * ( 1 / T - 1 / 239.81) / R) = 
(0.1802680734 - a) * R * T / 1013.3 ,
y * e ^ ( -5.57 * 10^3 * ( 1 / T - 1 / 77.5) / R) = 
(0.0571739895 - b) * R * T / 1013.3 ,
z * e ^ ( -0.90 * 10^3 * ( 1 / T - 1 / 20.4) / R) = 
(0.1715219686 - c) * R * T / 1013.3 ,
a > 0 , b > 0 , c > 0 } ,
{a, b, c}, {T, 1, 300}];
```

As you can see, I'm trying to solve a, b, and c with respect to T. The reason for x, y, and z is because I have to plot x, y, and z against T to calculate the change of fraction a in a, b, c mixture with respect to the change in T.

Any pointers or errors I'm making in the equation/code? Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Is `{T, 1, 300}` the range of parameter T?

Comment: Yes. T has to be a value between 1 and 300.

Comment: What is e? If it is exponantial function then you should use `E`

Comment: Be careful not to mix `=` and `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Use capital E for Exp

```
eqs[T_] = {x*E^(-23.78*10^3*(1/T - 1/239.81)/R) == (0.1802680734 - a)*
           R*T/1013.3, 
           y*E^(-5.57*10^3*(1/T - 1/77.5)/R) == (0.0571739895 - b)*R*
           T/1013.3, 
           z*E^(-0.90*10^3*(1/T - 1/20.4)/R) == (0.1715219686 - c)*R*
           T/1013.3, a > 0, b > 0, c > 0} /. {R -> 8.3145101, 
           x -> a/(a + b + c), y -> b/(a + b + c), z -> c/(a + b + c)};

soln[T_] := Check[NSolve[eqs[T], {a, b, c}, Reals] // Quiet, {{}}]

tab = DeleteCases[
       Table[{{T, a}, {T, b}, {T, c}} /. soln[T], {T, 0, 300, 2}], {{_, 
               a}, {_, b}, {_, c}}];

ListLogPlot[Transpose@Flatten[tab, 1], PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but your edited equations:

```
R = 8.3145101; x = a/(a + b + c); y = b/(a + b + c); z = c/(a + b + c);
soln = NSolve[{
x*Exp[-23.78*10^3*(1/T - 1/239.81)/R] == (0.1802680734 - a)*R*
 T/1013.3,
y*Exp[-5.57*10^3*(1/T - 1/77.5)/R] == (0.0571739895 - b)*R*T/1013.3,
z*Exp[-0.90*10^3*(1/T - 1/20.4)/R] == (0.1715219686 -c)*R*T/1013.3(*,a>0,b>0,c>0*)}, {a, b, c}]
```

Unfortunately NSolve doesn't succeed in solving th e equations.

Now a possible answer to your  question:

Here NMinimize is used to solve the 3 equations

```
mini[T_?NumericQ] :=NMinimize[ {1, {a/(a + b + c)*
  Exp[-23.78*10^3*(1/T - 1/239.81)/R] ==  (0.1802680734 - a)*R*T/1013.3, 
b/(a + b + c)*Exp[-5.57*10^3*(1/T - 1/77.5)/R] == (0.0571739895 - b)*R*
  T/1013.3,Exp[-0.90*10^3*(1/T - 1/20.4)/R] == (0.1715219686 - c)*R*
  T/1013.3 , a > 0, b > 0, c > 0 }}, {a, b, c}]
```

For given T you can calculate a[T],b[T],c[T]. For example

```
mini[10]
(* {1., {a -> 0.180268, b -> 0.057174, c -> 0.122621}} *)
```